# What - Missed all 2 branches for a While Loop condition in Junit

Tags: java, junit, code-coverage

What are the junit conditions missed for the below while loop?

**CompanyService.java :**

```
    @GET
@Path("/services")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getcompanyData(@QueryParam("comp") final String comp,
        @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    Response response = null;
    String company= null;
    if (comp!= null && !comp.isEmpty()) {
        company= comp;
    } else {
        company= getCompanyReqHeader(request);
    }

    response = responseBuilder.getcompanyData(company); // here calls getCompanyData of ResponseBuilder class
    return response ;
}


   public static String getCompanyReqHeader(HttpServletRequest request) {  
   //  code to get the companyname from request header
   }
```

**CompanyServiceTest.java**

```
    private static final String SVC_URL=  "http://localhost:8080/services/getcompanyData?comp=xxx"
@Test
public void testCompanyService() throws IOException, MalformedURLException {
    BufferedReader br = null;       
    StringBuilder response = null;      
    Assert.assertNotNull(SVC_URL);
    URL url = new URL(SVC_URL);
    Assert.assertNotNull(url);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();      
    Assert.assertNotNull(conn);     
    Assert.assertSame(200, conn.getResponseCode());                 
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));      
    Assert.assertNotNull(br);
    response = new StringBuilder();             
    String inputLine = null;    

    while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {               
        response.append(inputLine);
    }               
    conn.disconnect();
}
```

"All 2 branches missed" mark shown at the above while loop condition.
Could anybody suggest the Junit missed conditions for the above while loop

Comment: The branches in the provided code are `br.readLine() is null` and `br.readLine() is not null`. You have to test for both cases to satisfy your code coverage tool.

Comment: Oh.  So that means that your test covers 10-15% of the class that you're testing, and you want to know what the other 85-90% is?

Comment: Your test is making a call to your service.  But your service contains code that hasn't been run by the test.  I would love to tell you what code that is, but I left my crystal ball at home.

Comment: added service code..!

Comment: Are you sure you're actually running the code above?  It looks to me like you should have a null pointer exception.

Comment: @DavidWallace: I didnt add the logic of getCompanyReqHeader method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64846/discussion-between-lazyguy-and-david-wallace).

Comment: I see you've changed the code again since my last comment.  I have no intention of continuing to pursue these moving goalposts.  Sorry.  Maybe someone with more time and more patience than me will help you.